# Find the limiting distribution of $Y_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \frac{a^i}{a^{n+1}-1}$ for independent binary variable $X_i$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ be independent binary uniform random variable taking values in $\{0,1\}$.
For $a>1$, we define the random variable $Y_n$ as
$$Y_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \frac{a^i}{a^{n+1}-1}. $$
We denote the distribution subject to $Y_n$ by $p_n$.
I would like to know the limiting distribution $\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n$.

Indeed, when $a=2$, $(2^{n+1}-1)Y_n$ is subject to the uniform distribution on the set $\{0,1, \ldots, 2^{n+1}-1\}$. Hence, the limiting distribution $\lim_{n\to \infty} p_n$ is the uniform distribution on  the interval $[0,1]$. However, it is not so easy to solve this for general $a>1$.
More precisely, I would like to know the probability density function of the limiting distribution when it has the limiting distribution.
In particular, I would like to know the answer when $1<a<2$.

Since $a^{n+1}-1$ is close to $a^{n+1}$, we can consider the following variable instead of $Y_n$;
$$Z_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i a^{i-n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i a^{-i}. $$

In fact, I would like to know the form of the derivative of the probability density function.

Notice that the support of $Z_n$ is contained in $[0,1/(a-1)]$. Hence, the the support of the limiting distribution is also contained in $[0,1/(a-1)]$. I am interested in the value of the probability density function at the boundary $0$ and $1/(a-1)$.

Comment: Do the $X_i$ have the same distribution?

Comment: I forgot to say that $X_i$ is subject to the binary uniform distribution.

Comment: To Brian Moehring. You are right. Now, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Random note from my attempt to answer:  Your example of $a={\color{red}2}$ is equivalent to the limit $$\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{{\color{red}2}^kt}{{\color{red}2}^n-1}\right) \to \frac{\sin(t)}{t}$$ (which I'm not sure I've seen before).  The general case would effectively require you to find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{a^kt}{a^n-1}\right).$$

Comment: To Brian  Moehring. You are right. Your method was used in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830354/series-of-independent-bernoulli-variables
Hence, the case with a=2 is easy, and the case with 1<a<2 is more difficult.

Comment: Since $a^{n+1}-1$ is close to $a^{n+1}$, we ca replace $a^{n+1}-1$ by $a^{n+1}$.

Comment: Ahhh, that last comment does change my initial product (with the 2's) into a simpler form, and I do think I remember that one now.  I'm certainly not seeing a way to resolve the infinite product for any other value of $a>1$ though.  May I ask how you came upon this problem?  As in, did it come up within another problem, or are you interested in this for its own sake?

Comment: To Brian Moehring. This problem is related to the weight distribution of an error-correcting code. Do you know an error-correcting code, which is mathematically given as a vector space over finite field $F_2$?

Comment: @NN2 Thank you for your comment. The support of a normal distribution is the set of real numbers, i.e., the non-compact set. However, the support of $p_n$ is contained in $[0,1]$. Hence, the limit is not a normal distribution.

Comment: @NN2 The support of $p_n$ is contained in $[0,1/(a-1)]$ for any $n$. Hence, the support of the limiting distribution is contained in $[0,1/(a-1)]$.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is an integer, then I think $Y_n$ is uniform among "$n$-digit decimals" in base $a$ consisting of only $0$ and $1$.

- When $a=2$, this becomes uniform on $[0,1]$ since all numbers in this interval have a binary representation with only $0$s and $1$s.
- When $a=3$, numbers that have a $2$ in their ternary representation (like $0.1021$) are excluded. The set of numbers without any $2$s in their ternary representation resembles the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) (the Cantor set consists of numbers whose ternary expansion does not have any $1$s).
- I think this generalizes further similarly for other integers $a$.

Comment: Thank you to angryavian. I am more interested in the case when 1< a <2.