# Generate Two Random Variables by Using Only One Random Variable

Tags: random-variables, uniform-distribution

I have the following question asked in an interview: how can we use one generated random variable from uniform $U(0, 1)$ to generate two random variables from the same distribution $U(0, 1)$. My initial thoughts were to do some decomposition, say $x = f(x_1, x_2)$ where $x$ is from $U(0, 1)$ but in generally I was like headless on this decomposition. I am not sure how can we do this.

Comment: Is the question asking you to generate two *independent* uniform random variables?

Comment: Sure it was the only requirements?, if $x \sim U(0,\,1)$ then the variable $y=1-x \sim U(0,\,1)$, but are $100\%$ correlated, so maybe they were asking for uncorrelated variables, right?

Comment: An old _numerical_ trick, maybe not the best, was to generate $U$ on $(0,1)$, then to set $V$ to the fractional part of $1024\times U$, or some other multiplier which shifts the most significant bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [neat link between the uniform distribution and an infinite sequence of independent fair coin flips](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805296/represent-a-uniform0-1-random-variable-as-a-sum-of-independent-bernoulli1-2/1805305#1805305).

Sketch of one solution to the question that uses the above neat fact:

- Generate $x \sim U(0,1)$.
- Write $x$ in binary: $(0.x_1 x_2 x_3 \cdots)_2$ and use the above link to recognize that $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$ is a sequence of independent $\text{Bernoulli}(1/2)$ random variables.
- Use the bits of this binary representation to create two new numbers $x' := (0.x_1 x_3 x_5 \cdots)_2$ and $x'' = (0.x_2 x_4 x_6 \cdots)$. Note that $x'$ and $x''$ are independent.
- Use the link again to recognize that $x'$ and $x''$ are each distributed according to $U(0,1)$.

---

As mentioned in the comments, if the two generated random variables need not be independent, you can instead simply return $x \sim U(0,1)$ and $y := 1-x$. Or even $x \sim U(0,1)$ and $y:=x$.

Comment: Is it necessary to first convert the number to binary? Why not just take the digits from even decimal points for one number and odd for the other?